# Unknown symbol in module : printk_all_partitions

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have compiled this code:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/genhd.h> // declaration of  printk_all_partitions()


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");


int __init start (void) {

        printk ("evaluating the module ") ;
        printk_all_partitions();
        printk (" module inserted .. ");

        return 0 ;
}

void __exit x(void) {
        printk ("module unloaded ..");
}

module_init(start);
module_exit (x);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

makefile is:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wall
obj-m += printk_all_partitions.o

all :
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r )/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean :
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r )/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

when I run make I get

```
WARNING: "printk_all_partitions" [/root/c++/modulez/multiple_source_files/printk_plm/printk_all_partitions.ko] undefined!
```

egrep -w 'printk|printk_all_partitions' /proc/kallsyms :

```
ffffffff8162f135 T printk
ffffffff81ac7b46 T printk_all_partitions
```

Now the only difference between printk and printk_all_partitions is that printk_all_partitions does not exist in the Module.symvers
and printk is:

```
0x27e1a049  printk  vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL
```

By the time i finished the writing I found out that a function must be EXPORT_SYMBOL-ed too in order for it to work

but if (somehow) Modules.symvers was deleted , and the kernel sources were not available, both printk and printk_all_partitions are begin with a "T", what other way to know is one is exported or not?

Answer (score 1):

Normally this line

```
obj-m += printk_all_partitions.o
```

is the name of the module you're trying to create. In this case you're naming your module the same as an existing symbol, is this deliberate?